# Is there an opposite of "back to the roots"?

Tags: antonyms

I wondered whether or not there is an opposite of "back to the roots" in terms of development.

**Example using "back to the roots":**

> For the city to develop a stable infrastructure, they have to go back to the roots and live independently and more decentralized from bigger cities or even other countries.

**What I am looking for:**

> For the city to develop a stable infrastructure, they have to [...] and adopt technically, economically and socially essential purposes of regional planning from bigger cities or even other countries.

Comment: Continuing the metaphor, why not "branch out"?

Comment: ... move with the times.